# MySQL - Comparsion VARCHAR with INT

Tags: mysql, int, varchar

On my site user registration date stored as timestamp in varchar(20) column. I want to count how many users registered today, i written query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `users` WHERE `user_group` = 7 AND `reg_date > 1368993600
```

1368993600 - today 0:00. This query return me count of all users instead of count registered today. I edited query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM `users` WHERE `user_group` = 7 AND CAST(`reg_date` AS SIGNED) > 1368993600
```

But it still not working... How I can count users registered today?

Comment: 1) Why are you using a VARCHAR fields to store integers? 2) Why aren't you using a field of type TIMESTAMP? It will be a lot faster to process, even more if you add an index to that field.

Comment: Engine for this site did not written by me. I just try add this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deducting something wrong and your error is somewhere else. [See this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c25b/1), using the same data structure you are mentioning and using your first query without `CAST`, and you will see it's working fine. Only 3 rows are returned and are the ones that have a value greater than 1368993600.

Comment: You right. SQL Fiddle returns 3 rows. But on my server same query returns 470 - count of all users...

Comment: If in your server the data structure is the same and you are running the same query, then it means you have 470 rows with a `reg_date` greater than 1368993600. Can you do a `mysqldump` of your table and put it somewhere for me to download, so I can see what you are talking about?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just rechecked this. Query works right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count 
FROM `users` 
WHERE `user_group` = 7 
AND `reg_date` - timestamp(curdate()) >= 0
```